# Using set in insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

I was told by someone to use set in insert query like
`insert into tbl_student SET 
    name='myname', class='myclass'`. This query works fine but it is preferred over normal insert query?
Normal insert query is

```
insert into tbl (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)
```

Comment: Depends on what a **normal** insert query is ...

Comment: that is the ond syntax of `INSERT` supported in mysql.

Comment: MySQL provides this some INSERT syntaxes, you can use all of them; one of them uses SET clause, which indicates the column names explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No. I suspect that the 'normal' syntax is more common, I doubt that either syntax could generally be described as more preferable than the other.

Comment: Or is this execution time that matters?

Comment: Again, no. I doubt that it could make any discernible difference. At the point it does start to make a difference, you'll either be successful enough to employ someone to fix it, or too successful to care.